# Loading library with document.write from another JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prototype

I have an older validation form which is depends on the prototype.js library.

Unfortunately I can't include a reference to the prototype.js library on the page. I do not control that form's code.

How would I approach the issue of loading this outside of editing the pages that need it? That is, I need to load the library from another JavaScript library I **do** control. Let me explain.

Each page with the form has this include script:

```
<script src="http://domain/validationScript.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**And inside the script I was thinking of doing something like this...**

```
document.write(unescape(
    "%3Cscript src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1/prototype.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"
  ));
```

but it doesn't load `prototype.js` before the script.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Ok, it's clear with the DOM sequence that it has a race condition where I can't use the loaded script in the script that's writing the include to the page.

But then how can I load the library from a script that itself needs to execute the code from the library it's loading?

Comment: note: pages are loading jQuery as a default

Comment: note: thank you guys for helping out. I'm learning new things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating a new script element in the DOM, at the next point that one could be added.

This point is immediately after the current script element.

Any code in the current script element can't use it, because it won't be loaded until the execution of the current element has finished.

Since you are using jQuery you can use [`getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), which allows you to pass a callback method. Move any code that depends on the dynamically loaded script into the callback.

Comment: will I run into cross-domain issue?

Comment: Possibly, but you can always copy Prototype to the same origin.

Comment: though it seems like jQuery is being loaded at the bottom of the page, and veryfyForm(); is being loaded way above it. I don't have access to the page to modify it. verify.js doesn't see jQuery.

Comment: what if I wouldn't access to jQuery any other way I can do it?

Comment: The simplest option would be to move all the code into an `onload` handler so it runs after jQuery is available. Alternatively you can reproduce the functionality of `jQuery.getScript` (the source code is available), this is (IIRC) relatively complex as it deals with lots of cross-browser issues relating to dynamically loading script elements.

Comment: I was able to use modernizer load :) which was available to me.

Answer (score -1):

You should add the script to the head of the dom:

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1/prototype.js';
headID.appendChild(newScript);
```

Comment: That will give the same problem.